# Ephemeral shared volume in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm looking for a way to share an arbitrary directory in one Docker container with another, but without persisting the volumes between container creations.

The use case is sharing static assets between a web application and a web server like nginx. Both containers are built by an image. The web application's `Dockerfile` copies the static assets to a directory like `/var/www/public` when it's built. I want to avoid persisting the volume because the static assets are updated when the web application is built.

I've attempted this with a `docker-compose.yml` that looks like the following, but unfortunately this persists the volume and when a container is recreated with the new image, the contents of the shared volume aren't updated.

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  web:
    image: bswinnerton/nyc-restaurant-grades
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - www_data:/var/www/app/
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    depends_on:
      - web
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - www_data:/var/www/app/
    networks:
      - backend

volumes:
  www_data:

networks:
  backend:
```

And the web application's `Dockerfile` looks something like this:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

# Set working directory, where the commands will be ran:
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/app
WORKDIR /var/www/app

# Adding gems
COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5

# Adding project files
COPY . .

# Precompile assets
RUN bundle exec rails assets:precompile

CMD [ "bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb" ]
```

I considered using a `tmpfs` mount, but it appears they cannot be shared between containers.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re looking to do this in a Docker/Compose environment, I’d probably just use a folder on disk and configure it upon startup of the containers. Another alternative is to have your build pipeline copy the files out of one image and into another using `docker cp` to the build environment and `COPY` in the subsequent Dockerfile (assuming they're static files).

If you’re looking to do this in Kubernetes, this is achievable with emptyDir volumes and pods with multiple containers (sidecars).